# Non-verbal lyrics in songs – is there a nice name for these?

Tags: single-word-requests, lyrics

Often in songs, the lyrics will be "na na na", "doo doo doo", etc., in a particular section or part.  Is there a name for these sorts of sounds?  I've seen "non-lexical vocables" which, while being accurate, is a bit of a mouthful. It feels like there should be a snappier name, so if you were talking about the lyrics you could say, for example,

> Oh and during the ________ section, the backing vocals shouldn't be too loud.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Maybe *vocalizations*? Or perhaps the *scatting*, but that's too narrow and doesn't include melodic vocalizations like *la la la*.

Comment: Or "*[vocalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_warm_up#Vocalise)*"?

Comment: @DanBron - That's what we would call it in speech and language development. I can't think of anything else to use for it. "Vocalize" for a verb and "vocalizations" as a plural noun.

Comment: Hmm, Wikipedia calls these sounds [***vocables***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocable). From that article: *Such non-lexical vocables are often used in music, for example "la la la" or "dum dee dum"...*.

Comment: @Chenmunka I bet many non-Jazz singers who *use their voice as a musical instrument* would object to the art being narrowly defined as "jazz singing*. I think the term "*scatting*" is use more specifically to refer to the kind of improvised vocalizations used by traditional jazz singers (Fitzgerald etc). Problem is "*do re me fah so la ti do*" and "*la la la*" would not typically be called "*scatting*".

Comment: What's wrong with *la-las*? It may be a neologism, but it conveys the idea admirably.

Comment: Actually, singing using *do re me, etc.* is called *solfege* and is a training system for learning pitches and sight-singing.  Scatting is improvisational singing using non-word sounds.  La-la's, etc. are considered *vocalise*.

Comment: @DanBron thanks - i know about the "non-lexical vocables" term (i mention it in my question).  But it's too much of a mouthful, no pun intended.  I'm not going to say to someone else i'm recording a song with, for example, "during the non-lexical vocables section, can we make sure we don't get too loud".  I can barely even say it aloud, it's a tongue twister!

Comment: @dnagirl - "the la-las" works great if the lyrics actually are "la la la", etc, but i think it would be confusing if the lyrics were "bom bom bom ba-da" or something.

Comment: It looks like either CopperKettle or KristinaLopez should post a proper answer.  "During the vocalese" looks like the best fit for "during the section that goes 'bom-diddilly do do diddily ramala-ramala pop, yeah'".  It makes sense to call those "words" vocables, but the section, the lyric, is vocalese.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan they said "vocalise", but i like "vocalese" - it sounds like a language, which sort of fits.  Vocalise is a verb which is a bit confusing i think.  If you want to suggest "vocalese" in an answer i'll mark it correct.  thanks!

Comment: Well, @KristinaLopez provided the distinction that made sense to me.  CopperKettle had already provided the reference.  I simply used the spelling listed under "Jazz and World Music".  If neither of them post an answer by tomorrow, I'll do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of non-words to "sing" a melody is called ***"vocalise"*** (pronounced [voh-kuh-leez]), which is a noun and is defined in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vocalise) as:

> 1. a musical composition consisting of the singing of melody with vowel sounds or nonsense syllables rather than text, as for special
>      effect in classical compositions, in polyphonic jazz singing by
>      special groups, or in virtuoso vocal exercises.
> 2. any such singing exercise or vocalized melody.

Answer (score 8):

These are called **non-lexical vocables**.

An interesting video about them:

[History of Lyrics that aren't Lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_OzM2mE_uo)

And then the old fashioned:
[Wikipedia entry on their use in music.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music)

> Examples of popular music employing non-lexical vocables include:
>
> A cappella (singing without instrumental accompaniment, sometimes
> accompanied by a chorus of nonsense syllables)
>
> Beatboxing (vocal percussion)
>
> Doo-wop (style of rhythm and blues music that often
> employs nonsense syllables)
>
> Kobaïan (language used by French
> progressive rock band Magma)
>
> Hopelandic (gibberish language employed
> by the Icelandic post-rock band Sigur Rós)
>
> Van Morrison employed scat
> in his performances.[5]
>
> Scat singing influenced the development of doo-wop and hip hop. It was
> popular enough in doo-wop that Barry Mann and Gerry Goffin made it the
> subject of a 1961 song, Who Put the Bomp (in the Bomp, Bomp, Bomp)".
> It has also appeared in various genres of rock music. Jim Morrison of
> The Doors sings a chorus of slow scat on the song "Cars Hiss By My
> Window", trying to replicate a harmonica solo he had heard, as well as
> on the song "Roadhouse Blues"; scat singing also notably opens the
> B-side of Joe Walsh's 1973 album The Smoker You Drink, The Player You
> Get with the song "Meadow". The technique was employed in the song
> "The Great Gig in the Sky" by Pink Floyd, as well as the R&B song
> "Rubber Biscuit" by The Chips (also as by The Blues Brothers).
>
> Scat also makes appearances in newer genres, including industrial
> music, in the chorus of Ministry's 1991 song "Jesus Built My Hotrod";
> nu metal music, in the band Korn whose lead singer Jonathan Davis has
> incorporated scat singing into songs such as "Twist", "Ball Tongue",
> "Freak on a Leash", "B.B.K.", "Beat it Upright" and "Liar"; and the
> heavy metal subgenre of death metal, where scat singing is used by
> John Tardy of the band Obituary. Jack Black incorporates scat into
> several Tenacious D songs, most notably: "Tribute", "Cosmic Shame",
> "Classico," "Jesus Ranch," Low Hangin' Fruit," and "Bowie". Singer
> JoJo performs ad-libbed scats on the track "Yes or No". Other modern
> examples include "Under Pressure" by Queen (band), "Rag Doll" by
> Aerosmith, "Under My Voodoo" by Sublime, "No! Don't Shoot" by Foxy
> Shazam, "Ma Meeshka Mow Skwoz" by Mr. Bungle, "In My Bed" by Amy
> Winehouse, and "Stuck in the Middle" by Mika. Scatman John
> successfully combined scat and early-1990s electronic dance music.
>
> Examples by popular non-anglophone singers using such techniques
> include "Bla Bla Bla" by Gigi D'Agostino, Eena Mina Dika in the
> Bollywood film Aasha, Eduard Khil's "I Am Glad, Cause I'm Finally
> Returning Back Home" (known as "Trololo") sung entirely without
> lyrics, "Restless" (Fu Zao) by Faye Wong and "Lagu Lagu" by Sa
> Dingding.
>
> Due to the wide-ranging vocal styles used in popular music,
> occasionally songs have been mistakenly categorized as having
> non-lexical vocables, when in fact the singers are performing actual
> lyrics rendered partially (or completely) unintelligible to the ear of
> certain (but not all) listeners. Two famous 1960s examples are "Louie
> Louie" as recorded by The Kingsmen and "Wooly Bully" by Sam the Sham
> and the Pharaohs.

Comment: thanks - i know about the "non-lexical vocables" term (i mention it in my question). But it's too much of a mouthful, no pun intended. I'm not going to say to someone else i'm recording a song with, for example, "during the non-lexical vocables section, can we make sure we don't get too loud". I can barely even say it aloud, it's a tongue twister!

Comment: Actually,  i think "doo wop" works fine- even if the song isn't a doo-wop genre song as such, and even if the syllables "doo" and "wop" don't feature, i think most people would guess what i mean if i say "during the doo-wop section..."

Answer (score 4):

Parelcon is another useful concept here. Parelcon can be, like, when a speaker adds vocal ticks or syllables like "like" earlier in this sentence.

Comment: As defined by the Free Dictionary, [_parelcon_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Parelcon) appears to be a good word to describe Stevie Wonder's phrasing in "[Signed, Sealed, Delivered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBDqgSOwxkc)," where he sings (at 1:02–1:05) "I've done a lot of foolish things-uh that I really didn't mean-uh."

Comment: Like The Fall's Mark E Smith, who-ah "sings" like-uh THIS-ah!? Nice word

Answer (score 0):

Critics use the term ''burden'' to describe Ophelia's nonsense singing in Hamlet:
♪♪ Hey. non nony. nony. hey. nony ♪♪
♪♪ Down. a-down. a-down. a-down ♪♪

Comment: Can you please provide a reference? Answers without citations are often deleted.

Comment: A burden is specifically a chorus or refrain, including one made up of nonsense (hey nonny no, etc) but not necessarily nonsense. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burden

Answer (score 0):

"Folderol"- are the nonsensical syllablic words in the refrain of a song.
Folderol stems from "Folderal" which meant nonsense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).