# A to the B to the C: some kind of slang

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms, slang

I've often heard, especially in songs where slang is commonly used (pop, rap, etc.), people use a weird structure: something like "A to the B to the C...", where A, B, C, etc. are usually letters of the alphabet that make up some word. To me it sounds like the speaker is spelling out a word, for example "YOU" would be Y to the O to the U.

What is the real meaning of that structure? Where does it come from? Does it have anything to do powers and exponents (say, n **to the** third power), is it short for "moving over **to the** next letter", or is it related to something else?

**Edited to add examples**

I didn't expect people here to not recognize this pattern. I see there are already 3 close votes, this is crazy. If you search for "x to the y" on Google, and replace x and y with various letters, you will find several examples, although the vast majority of them seem to be related to rap and hip hop. Some examples:

**Fergie - Fergalicious**
According to Wikipedia, "Fergalicious was a commercial success in the United States and moderately so in several other countries. In the United States, it peaked at number two on the Billboard Hot 100 and at number one on the Pop Songs chart. "Fergalicious" was certified 4× platinum". In this song, you can hear "T to the A to the S T E Y, girl, you tasty", and the same goes for the word "delicious".

**Eminem ft. Nate Dogg - Shake that**
In this song you can hear "Two to the one from the one to the three", with numbers, so I'm not sure it has exactly the same purpose, but it definitely looks like the same pattern. I have no idea what it could mean though, and I can't find any info online.

**Title of Reddit post**
The title of this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PandR/comments/hpvig4/m_to_the_e_to_the_m_and_e_this_meme_is_really/) reads "M to the E to the M to the E", which spells out the word "meme", and apparently is used to introduce some kind of meme related to a show.

**Modern Family (TV show)**
In [this video](https://youtu.be/aGVrC8f7VIE?t=43) taken from an American sitcom, at 0:43, you can hear the man say "D to the Y to the L" to refer to Dylan, probably just as a way to appear "cool" and speak like younger people (I don't really know much about the context, I haven't watched the show, I just stumbled upon this example on the web).

**Cheerleaders**
Searching for "L to the E" (using two letters more or less at random), I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYZGAS4DkTM) on YouTube where you can hear some cheerleaders say "L to the E T S G O" (let's go).

Comment: It sounds like a modern variant on the lyrical filler, just introduced for lyrical effects (hey-nonny-no; fol di rol, yeh-yeh-yeh ... ). So I've got to CV as off-topic, song lyrics, and intentionally devoid of semantic substance.

Comment: Mathematically, it's simple addition: If we add a Y to the O to the U, we get YOU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How is this syntactic phenomenon off-topic? A perfectly on-topic answer would be "This is just nonsense filler that occurs sometimes in poetry and songs" or "Yes, here's the history of its use in lyrics."

Comment: I associate it with cheers in American cheerleading, which often involve spelling, but I'm unable to prove that's the origin. If you're spelling something out and want to emphasise each letter according to some rhythm, you need some kind of filler between each letter and 2 syllables ("to the") is about right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, if it was just a "stupid filler", then I guess I would have heard several random variations of it, but I don't think I have heard many others. Well, wait, there's also "give me an A, give me a B, give me a C..." But "give me" has a meaning that makes sense somehow, "to the" doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, *you* read as a part of a mathematical formula would tell me to multiply *y, o*, and *u*, not to add them up

Comment: @Mitch Song lyrics when difficult to interpret definitively though using standard constructions are categorically off-topic. How much more so contrivances akin to codes or puzzles. Unless OP provides evidence that this phenomenon really does have a closer relationship to the English language than say a game of hangman, I fail to see how it can be considered standard English usage. Note that OP asks for the 'real meaning'. I'm reminded of Brian May's response when asked what the 'real meaning' of Bohemian Rhapsody was. 'Come on ...' or words to that effect. He was honest.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I added some examples in my question.

Comment: It comes from the [Speed Scientific School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._B._Speed_School_of_Engineering) cheer:  E to the X, D Y D X, E to the X, D X.  Slip stick, sliderule, yeah Speed School!

Comment: It should be noted that a [poem from 1910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball%27s_Sad_Lexicon) immortalized the phrasing "Tinker to Evers to Chance".

Comment: Old MacDonald had a farm, E to the I to the E to the I to the O. Not so catchy as the original. There have been lyrics that use spellings (sometimes sensational, sometimes mangled) or just letters as lyrical fillers for many years. 'There was a farmer had a dog and Bingo was his name-O: B-I-N-G-O ...'. Reger went a few stages further into encryption and wrote _Fantasy and Fugue on B-A-C-H_, Op. 46, an instrumental piece. The 'A to the B ...' variety seem just another contrivance, perhaps the lyrical equivalent of Picasso portraits. A loose connection to the norm.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, a request for an explanation of the lyrics of **one particular** song would indeed be off topic. That, however, does not mean that a request for an explanation of a **pattern** that can be found at a number of unrelated places is off topic. The OP's edits make a case that this is a request of the latter kind. If the pattern is just a nonsensical filler, that constitutes an answer to the question, not a reason for dismissing it.

Comment: @jsw29 Already discussed in general at [Non-verbal lyrics in songs: is there a nice name for these?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211716/non-verbal-lyrics-in-songs-is-there-a-nice-name-for-these/211725#211725). I don't see any spelling-out-and-inserting-_to_'s-specific term there.

Comment: The question is now closed as opinion-based, but it is not at all clear what is supposed to make it opinion-based. A reasonable hypothesis about the matter has been offered above by @StuartF and there needn't be anything opinion-based about an answer that would prove or disprove that hypothesis.

Comment: There are 3 votes to reopen, but I'm voting to keep it closed, on 3 counts. Firstly, it asks multiple questions and is therefore too broad; it needs an [edit] to focus on one aspect only in order for it to be acceptable on *any* Stack Exchange site. Secondly, the title then needs to be turned into a question. Thirdly (and this is where editing won't help), I agree with @EdwinAshworth: asking for the **meaning** of a **lyric-writing technique** and its **origin** is *literary analysis* – which is off-topic on EL&U but would be both on-topic and welcome on our sister site [Literature.SE]. :-)

Comment: I want to add that German Rap Songs have identical phrases with the cognate "zu dem". Although this was most likely calqued in immitation of English, it shows verbal understanding. Indeed I agree it sounds of movement, like "to the windows, to the walls, till sweat drop down... " (Lil' John - Get Low (2008)) and thus most likely of cheering figures in origin. Spelling instruction in a school setting would seem to be the only sensible alternative, and not all too sensible at that unless somebody knows corroborating evidence. The most basic comparison is of sequences, "from A to Z" of course

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Indeed it's asking too many questions at once. Should focus on "A to the B" or "B to the C", but both at once is entirely too much /s